# Is it formal to use "If" in a business email

Tags: word-choice

Is it formal to use "if" in a business email.
For instance, "If you have any questions or concerns...." 
Our division's seniors always use it to answer the customer`s emails.
Is it formal or is there any other words to express the same? 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is it formal". There's certainly nothing wrong with this construction, and inviting the other party to clarify their question or ask additional questions is fairly common in business correspondence... or in correspondence generally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's considered formal English usage in business correspondence, and, indeed, it's almost obligatory. I'm hard put to think of any way for one business person to communicate with another entity what to do in the case that a particular effort has mailed to satisfy the entity addressed,, without useing "if", or a much more wordy alternative, for example, "in the event we have not answered your questions sufficiently, or in the event that you have other concerns". If is much more concise, simple, and easier to understand.

Comment: "Yes, it's considered formal English usage in business correspondence, and, indeed, it's almost obligatory."           Thank you very much.  Feel free to use the expression now.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out already, *If[...]* is a completely legal construct in a formal setting.

That being said, I myself tend to use another alternative- *"Should you have[...]"*.

> *Should you have* any questions or concerns, please feel free to [...]

Comment: "Should you have any questions or concerns, please feel free to [...]"   Thank you very much. It is what I have been looking for.